# Move to Element Syntax in Seleniumbasic - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver, vba

I have looked across everywhere to find answers but could not get it, so would like your help in guiding me.
Selenium Basic (Excel VBA ) is giving me syntax error at the time of compilation.
My Objective is to move the mouse to a known element.

Here are the codes

```
 Dim driver As New WebDriver
 Dim actions As Selenium.actions
 driver.Start "chrome", "http://anywebsite.com"
 driver.get "/"

 WebElement we = driver.FindElementByClass("MyClassName")
 actions.MoveToElement (we)
```

It gives me an error at the compilation level as and FindElementByClass is highlighted. However in the watch window I can see values against it.

> Compile Error: Sub or Function Not Defined

Would request if you can guide me since in the watch

Comment: Change `WebElement we = driver.FindElementByClass("MyClassName")`  to `Set we = driver.FindElementByClass("MyClassName")`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I also changed actions.MoveToElement(we) to driver.actions.MoveToElement(we) however the mouse seems not be moving at all. Did I miss something. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
driver.actions.MoveToElement(we)
```

to

```
driver.actions.MoveToElement(we).perform
```